# ¿Por qué la función recursiva devuelve `undefined`?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer una función recursiva que imprima en consola los números del 1 al 15.

Tengo este código que funciona:

```
function contarBien(contador){
    if(!contador){
        var contador = 1
    }
    if(contador) {
        if(contador <=15){
            console.log(contador++)
            return contarBien(contador)
        } else {
            return "final"
        }
    }
}
```

Pero lo primero que intenté es que en el segundo if, en lugar de poner `if(contador)` hubiera un `else`

```
    else {
        if(contador <=15){
            console.log(contador++)
            return contarBien(contador)
        } else {
            return "final"
        }
    }
```

Sin embargo esto me retorna `undefined`. No entiendo por qué si al volver a llamar la función `contarBien(contador)`, ya estaría creada la variable contador y por tanto el `if(!contador)` no se ejecuta y entraría a ejecutarse el else.

Comment: Hola Bayes-T, el error está en tu última frase, **`"no entiendo por qué si al volver a llamar la función"`**, la trampa está en que si entras en el `if`, no entras en el `else` y por lo tanto no llamas a la función.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una función "retorna" `undefined` cuando no se ejecuta ninguna instrucción `return`. Como es el caso de la primera rama del `if`.

Cuando hay una cadena de condicionales se evalúan las condiciones de cada rama en orden hasta que alguna se cumpla.

Entonces el código de la rama cuya condición se cumple es ejecutado.

```js
if (true) {
    console.log("Cuando se ejecuta está rama")
}
else {
    console.log("Esta otra no se ejecuta")
}

console.log("Entonces el siguiente código en ejecutarse es el que está justo después de la cadena de condicionales")
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo, el código del `else` no sé ejecuta. De manera similar, cuando encadenas los condicionales en tu código se ejecuta la rama:

```
var contador = 1
```

Que carece de `return`.

---

Ya que realmente no necesitas que la función devuelva nada, te propongo un código más simple:

```js
function contar(contador){
    if(contador > 0) {
        contar(contador - 1)
        console.log(contador)
    }
}

contar(10)
```